# How do I not show my Avatar Picture in Every Microsoft Office App?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, office365

How do I not show my Avatar in every app? I just don't want to see it, only my name. Don't want to look at icon photo all day. Is there a way to hide remove the picture in upper right? Deleting the photo https://account.microsoft.com/profile/ will replace it with default.

[image]

Microsoft Windows doesn't do an ideal job of condensing a high quality photo, loses too much resolution visibility btw, makes it look worse

Comment: You already found out the options, one is default, the other is what you want to add. There's no option to do what you want.

Comment: hi @John I am using it productively, I have written over 100 word documents, I just dont like to see it, consider it a styling theme change

Comment: Thanks.  I can't help with the avatar as it is built right in.

Comment: I also don’t believe this particular UI element can be hidden or disabled

Comment: 1. Make an image of a solid color, that of the background screen color, to use as your avatar image. 2. Or use another office application, such as LibreOffice.

Comment: It seems to be by design and cannot be removed